# how to convert the date to timestamp through code

Tags: android, timestamp, android-date

how to convert the current date to time-stamp through code

```
    String timeFormat = "dd.MM.yy, h:mm a";
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat);
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    Log.d("print"+c.getTime());
```

is it possible to convert the c.getTime to timestamp

this is my code but i dont know how to convert it to timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp, that is, in what format do you want it? In what sense doesn’t you `formattedDate` qualify as a timestamp? Maybe best if you give an example of your desired result. The question is easy enough, only not when we don’t know what you want.

Comment: I am sure this question has been asked and answered more than once before. Your search engine will give you a good answer faster than anyone can enter one here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current milliseconds from the current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785200/how-can-i-get-the-current-milliseconds-from-the-current-time)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the documentation,
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()
the function `getTime()` of `Date` object returns the

> time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

which is the timestamp that you want, so

```
Date d = c.getTime();
long timestamp = d.getTime();
```

would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Have 2 way to get current Timestamp. In your code `c.getTime()` is enough

```
Date date = new Date();
long timestamp = date.getTime();
```

OR

```
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score -1):

System.currentTimeMillis()

this will return the timestamp of cutrrent date time